# On Google TV How do I make Fullscreen Activity hide title and button properly?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, google-tv

It would seem that the Fullscreen Activity Demo/Template does not behave the same on Google TV with the way Status/Navigation/Action bar are handled.  Note: to make the default template work on Honeycomb I had to make a slight change to the provided `SystemUiHiderHoneycomb` class ([details](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/57090/1/templates/activities/FullscreenActivity/root/src/app_package/util/SystemUiHiderHoneycomb.java.ftl))

Question: Should the Template work properly? (I think yes). Is there a good way of fixing it without special handling for Google TV detection?  What's a good way of achieving the same result of hiding the title at the top and the button at the bottom?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new application via Android Tools wizard
2. Use Fullscreen Activity as first and only activity
3. perform code modification to `SystemUiHiderHoneycomb` class ([details](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/57090/1/templates/activities/FullscreenActivity/root/src/app_package/util/SystemUiHiderHoneycomb.java.ftl))

I tested this on a Google TV emulator and on a real device with the same result. (I also tested it without the change in step 3).

[image: Screenshot of default Fullscreen Activity]

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, you need to ask for Theme.Holo.Light.noactionbar in your manifest.

Comment: Well, it hides the ActionBar completely but I was rather hoping for a more dynamic effect like on other devices. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a programmatic way to do this if you don't want to muck with the theme in the Manifest file.

See: http://emergentbit.blogspot.com/2012/12/andorid-quick-tip-remove-title-bar-from.html

TL;DR

```
// Remove title bar
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
// Remove notification bar
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```